# Reportviewer showing #Error for mysql timestamp

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, reportviewer

I am trying to generate a reportviewer using C#. The dataset has been populated from a mysql table which has ID, TimeStamp.

```
+------+---------------------+
| ID   | TimeStamp           |
+------+---------------------+
| 1001 | 2009-06-09 13:24:50 |
| 1002 | 2013-04-03 21:47:47 |
+------+---------------------+
```

A quick investigation of the dataset shows the following for the above data set.

```
ID,TimeStamp
1001,09/06/2009 1:24:50 PM
1002,03/04/2013 9:47:47 PM
```

But on the actual report I am seeing an "**#Error**". I have been trying to get this to work. If I replace the TimeStamp with a string of message it does show up the value.
I am not doing any conversion, and I just wanted to display the raw data straight from MySQL to the report.

Can someone direct me on the right path here please. I am using Visual Studio 2010 for C# with .Net 4.0 for the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to find the issue and fixed it. It was related to the connection string. After removing the

`"Allow Zero Datetime=true;"`

everything started to work the way it is suppose to work. Hope this will help someone else!
The strange part is, my dataset does not have any zero datetime values ("0000-00-00 00:00:00"). Not sure if this is in fact a bug!